# How to avoid OOM in hsqldb while doing a merge?

Tags: java, sql, merge, hsqldb

I have two tables where the first is very large (>50M rows):

```
CREATE CACHED TABLE Alldistances (
    word1 VARCHAR(70), 
    word2 VARCHAR(70), 
    distance INTEGER, 
    distcount INTEGER
);
```

and a second that can be also quite large (>5M rows):

```
CREATE CACHED TABLE tempcach (
    word1 VARCHAR(70), 
    word2 VARCHAR(70), 
    distance INTEGER, 
    distcount INTEGER
);
```

Both tables have indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX mulalldis ON Alldistances (word1, word2, distance);
CREATE INDEX multem ON tempcach (word1, word2, distance);
```

In my java program I am using prepared statements to fill/preorganize data in the tempcach table and then I merge the table to alldistances with:

```
MERGE INTO Alldistances alld USING ( 

    SELECT word1, 
           word2, 
           distance, 
           distcount FROM tempcach 

    ) AS src (

        newword1, 
        newword2, 
        newdistance, 
        newcount

    ) ON (

            alld.word1 = src.newword1 
        AND alld.word2 = src.newword2 
        AND alld.distance = src.newdistance 

    ) WHEN MATCHED THEN 

        UPDATE SET alld.distcount = alld.distcount+src.newcount 

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 

        INSERT (

            word1, 
            word2, 
            distance, 
            distcount

        ) VALUES (

            newword1, 
            newword2, 
            newdistance, 
            newcount
        );
```

The tempchach table is then dropped or truncated and filled with new data.
During the merge I get the OOM, which is i guess because the whole table is loaded into memory during the merge. So I will have to merge in batches, but can i do that in SQL or do it in my java program. Or is there a smart way to avoid OOM while merging?

Comment: Is 50kk 50,000 (50K) or 50,000,000 (50M) ?

Comment: Are you using Oracle or SQL-Server?  Did you intend sql to mean sql-server?

Comment: OP is using HSQLDB, which is an RDBMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to merge in chunks (batches) in SQL. You need to

- limit the number of rows from the temp table in each chunk
- delete those same rows
- repeat

The SELECT statement should use an ORDER BY and LIMIT

```
SELECT word1, 
       word2, 
       distance, 
       distcount FROM tempcach
       ORDER BY primary key or unique columns 
       LIMIT 1000

) AS src (
```

After the merge, the delete statement will select the same rows to delete

```
DELETE FROM tempcach WHERE primary key or unique columns IN
      (SELECT primary key or unique columns FROM tempcach 
       ORDER BY primary key or unique columns LIMIT 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, just because this kind of thing annoys me, why are you selecting all the fields of the temporary table in a subselect?  Why not the simpler SQL:

```
MERGE INTO Alldistances alld USING tempcach AS src (
    newword1, 
    newword2, 
    newdistance, 
    newcount
) ON (
        alld.word1 = src.newword1 
    AND alld.word2 = src.newword2 
    AND alld.distance = src.newdistance 
) WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET alld.distcount = alld.distcount+src.newcount 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (
        word1, 
        word2, 
        distance, 
        distcount
    ) VALUES (
        newword1, 
        newword2, 
        newdistance, 
        newcount
    );
```

What you need to have the database avoid loading the whole table into memory is indexing on both tables.

```
CREATE INDEX all_data ON Alldistances (word1, word2, distance);
CREATE INDEX tempcach_data ON tempcach (word1, word2, distance);
```

Comment: Thanks for the improvement. As this is my first program using a database I'm pretty happy that this merge command does what I want and aesthetics are only of secondary concern.